# Multiple instances of self.__WB_MANIFEST

Tags: service-worker, workbox, quasar

(Related to [this question](https://forum.quasar-framework.org/topic/7808/injectmanifest-precaching-not-working))

I am using quasar v2.0.0-beta.5 and "workbox-webpack-plugin": "^5.1.4", following a pwa tutorial. I am now working on the service workers part using workboxPluginMode: 'InjectManifest' in quasar.conf.js. My custom-service-worker.js is just:

```
import { precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching'
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST)
```

I get the following error when loading the pwa

> Uncaught not-an-array: The parameter 'entries' passed into
> 'workbox-precaching.PrecacheController.addToCacheList()' must be an
> array

I have updated to lastest version of Workbox: `npm install --save-dev workbox-webpack-plugin@^6.1.0` to see if it makes a difference and now I get the following error during the `quasar dev -m pwa`

> Multiple instances of self.__WB_MANIFEST were found in your SW source.
> Include it only once. For more info, see GoogleChrome/workbox#2681

The problem is that without fixing this problem, I am not able to debug the different cache strategies.

> Platform (please complete the following information): Quasar Version:
> v2.0.0-beta.5 @quasar/app Version: v3.0.0-beta.7 Quasar mode: [ ] SPA
> [ ] SSR [x ] PWA [ ] Electron [ ] Cordova [ ] Capacitor [ ] BEX Tested
> on: [ ] SPA [ ] SSR [x ] PWA [ ] Electron [ ] Cordova [ ] Capacitor [
> ] BEX OS: windows 10 Node: v14.15.1 NPM: 6.14.8 Yarn: 1.22.10
> Browsers: chrome (latest) iOS: Android: Electron:

Comment: Getting the same problem!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this in your service worker file.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it problems, just add this code in service-worker.js

```js
precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST || []);
const { assets } = global.serviceWorkerOption;

let assetsToCache = [...assets, './'];

assetsToCache = assetsToCache.map((path) => {
  return new URL(path, global.location).toString();
});

// When the service worker is first added to a computer.
self.addEventListener('install', (event) => {
  // Perform install steps.
  if (DEBUG) {
    console.log('[SW] Install event');
  }

  // Add core website files to cache during serviceworker installation.
  event.waitUntil(
    global.caches
      .open(CACHE_NAME)
      .then((cache) => {
        return cache.addAll(assetsToCache);
      })
      .then(() => {
        if (DEBUG) {
          console.log('Cached assets: main', assetsToCache);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
      })
  );
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).